# javascript not working with php variable when retrieving information from linux command

Tags: javascript, php

Below image show my code.

$usernam = `sudo grep -w "navneet" "/var/www/mcloud/modules/demo_cmp/.cmpinfo.txt" | cut -d ":" -f7`;

function check()

```
{
    var username = "<?php echo $usernam; ?>";
    alert(usernam);
    return false;
}
```

I am retrieving value of $usernam variable by linux command and I want to use this variable value in javascript. But unfortunately javascript stop working after adding value of php variable. Please help me to short out my problem.

[image]

Comment: You need to share the code.. not a screenshot of it

Comment: check your browser console to see if there is any error

Comment: Sorry for that but have no idea to add all kind of code means javascript,html,and php code simulteniously

Comment: @LokeshBhandari You just need to give us the code you provided in the screenshot. Not sure why that's harder than giving a screenshot. Anyways it's because you are missing a semi-colon. An easy way to notice that is to [turn error reporting on in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display).

Comment: Problem is with retriving value from linux command please any one check it

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.

I have add trim in my linux command which used to retrieve my record.

$usernam = trim(`sudo grep -w "navneet" "/var/www/mcloud/modules/demo_cmp/.cmpinfo.txt" | cut -d ":" -f7`);

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $sim = 'hello world';

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sim = '<?php echo $sim; ?>';

</script>
```

Other than that, if you really want to "interact" between PHP and JavaScript you should use Ajax.

Comment: still this code not work

Comment: Problem is with linux command use in php variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function check(){
var username = "<?php echo $usernam; ?>";
alert(username);
}
</script>
```

What you are doing wrong is placing quotes with JS variable `username` which should not be there.

Comment: problem is with retrieving variable from linux command

Answer (score 0):

Open Google Chrome or other browser with developer/debugging capabilities. Navigate to the page with your code. View source code or open Developer tools and check the lines referent to var username in Element or Source panel. Also check Console panel.

Also, you need validate/clean/transform PHP variable $usernam in PHP to ensure it a valid string that suit your needs (an error or warning message is not an username).

Answer (score 0):

I give you a sample code. Think that you have to execute the php with a system or exec function. If you only write the code inside a variable, the variable will only have the text nor the result.

```
<?php
  $usernam = system('sudo grep -w "navneet" "/var/www/mcloud/modules/demo_cmp/.cmpinfo.txt" | cut -d ":" -f7');
?>

<script>
  function check(){
    var username = "<?php echo $usernam; ?>";
    alert(username);
  }
</script>
```

Check if that is useful for you. I wish it

Answer (score -1):

Remove single quote from alert i.e.

```
  alert(username);
```

okay sorry for this answer. I only refer your screen shot.

Try this one

```
{
var username = "<?php echo $usernam; ?>";
```

**alert(usernam);** replace with **alert(username);**

```
 return false;
}
```